# Compute a least square only on n best values of an array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares

I have :

```
print(self.L.T.shape)
print(self.M.T.shape)

(8, 3)
(8, 9082318)

self.N = np.linalg.lstsq(self.L.T, self.M.T, rcond=None)[0].T
```

which is working fine and return

```
(9082318, 3)
```

But

I want to perform a kind of sort on M and compute the solution only on the best 8 - n values of M.
Or ignore values of M below and/or higher than a certain value.

Any pointer on how to do that would be extremely appreciated.
Thank you.

Tried to copy [this solution](http://alexhwilliams.info/itsneuronalblog/2018/02/26/censored-lstsq/) exactly but it return an error

The original working function but basically it's just one line.
M is a stack of 8 grayscale images reshaped.
L is a stack of 8 light direction vectors.

M contains shadows but not always at the same location in the image.
So I need to remove those pixel from the computation but L must retains its dimensions.

```
def _solve_l2(self):
    """
    Lambertian Photometric stereo based on least-squares
    Woodham 1980
    :return: None

    Compute surface normal : numpy array of surface normal (p \times 3)
    """
    self.N = np.linalg.lstsq(self.L.T, M.T, rcond=None)[0].T
    print(self.N.shape)
    self.N = normalize(self.N, axis=1)  # normalize to account for diffuse reflectance
```

Here is the borrowed code from the link for trying to resolve this :
L and M as previously used

```
    Ma = self.M.copy()
    thresh = 300
    Ma[self.M <= thresh] = 0
    Ma[self.M > thresh] = 1
    Ma = Ma.T

    self.M = self.M.T
    self.L = self.L.T
    print(self.L.shape)
    print(self.M.shape)
    print(Ma.shape)
    A = self.L  
    B = self.M
    M = Ma  #http://alexhwilliams.info/itsneuronalblog/2018/02/26/censored-lstsq/

    # else solve via tensor representation
    rhs = np.dot(A.T, M * B).T[:,:,None] # n x r x 1 tensor
    T = np.matmul(A.T[None,:,:], M.T[:,:,None] * A[None,:,:]) # n x r x r tensor
    self.N = np.squeeze(np.linalg.solve(T, rhs)).T # transpose to get r x n
```

return

```
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Comment: You seems to need to transpose something somewhere, but without the code it's hard to say where.

Comment: added code but basically the code is just one line.
explained more what is L and M

Comment: Is that code giving you the `ValueError` ?

Comment: No the code I posted is functionnal but takes all values from M. I posted the copied code that return a singular error

Comment: I am not understanding you, sorry. Perhaps you may benefit from reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and try to modify your question accordingly.

Comment: yes sorry I wanted to state the problem clearly without my tries. Asking for a method rather than correcting code